# Custom module controller not working magento2

Tags: magento2

I have added a sample custom module in Magento 2. I have two controller function for admin panel page,

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin_magento2/sample/index/index/
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin_magento2/sample/sampletwo/index/
```

First url only display page. The second one displays 404 or redirecting to dashboard.

Please help me someone to solve this.

**Note**

I have added admin panel menu for first url only.

app\code\Test\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index.php

```
namespace Test\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app\code\Test\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Sampletwo\Index.php

```
namespace Test\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Sampletwo;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app\code\Test\Sample\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Test_Sample::parent" title="Sample" module="Test_Sample" sortOrder="100" resource="Test_Sample::parent"/>
        <add id="Test_Sample::index" title="Sample Index" module="Test_Sample" sortOrder="10" action="sample/index" resource="Test_Sample::index" parent="Test_Sample::parent"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

app\code\Test\Sample\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="sample" frontName="sample">
            <module name="Test_Sample" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: app\code\Custom\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Sampletwo\Index.php ?

Comment: yes that is another controller

Comment: Please paste your controller code with path in question

Comment: yes edited please see the question

Comment: show your routes.xml

Comment: Yes added @Ramkishan

Answer (score 1):

your action should be sample/sampletwo in menu.xml

Comment: Yes  If I added it in menu it's working. But with adding menu in controller it redirects to dashboard

Comment: show your routes.xml

Comment: I added routes.xml in my question. Please see that

Comment: change your action sample/sampletwo  in menu.xml

Comment: it will work  @VigneshBala

Comment: I don't needed menu for sample/sampletwo/index. So only I am not added in menu. If am adding menu for sample/sampletwo it's working

Comment: yes you dont need to give another index after sampletwo

Comment: yes. I added new controller like sample/index/testing it redirects to the dashboard. How can I make it working @Ramkishan

Comment: where is your controller file in this case ?

Comment: @VigneshBala sample/sampletwo in this action sample is your frontname in routes.xml and sampletwo is folder name in controller/adminhtml/sampletwo

Comment: app\code\Test\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Testing.php This is the filepath and my url is http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin_magento2/sample/index/testing

Comment: what is url of this menu when inspect this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51278/discussion-between-vignesh-bala-and-ramkishan).

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to access modules/functionality in the backend (Adminhtml), Magento checks for the presence of the secret `Form Keys`, and if/when someone does attempt to access an action and doesn't supply a valid FormKey and/or supplies an Invalid FormKey - the Adminhtml AbstractAction (Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction) will route the user Admin UIX defined Startup page (which is usually the Dashboard page)

[This mechanism serves a "security checkpoint" to prevent users from accessing portions of the Backend that they don't have access to]

---

When accessing options from the Admin UIX Menu - Magento will automatically add the FormKey for you. That is why you are able to access the first URL v/s not able to access the second URL.

---

To prevent the check for FormKey you have two options:

*(a) Turn off FormKey Validation*

**Navigation:** Stores -> Settings : Configuration -> Advanced : Admin -> Security -> Setup "Add Secret Key to URLs" to "No"

It's very important to remember that doing so will turn off Secret Key Validation, and therefore *may* make your application vulnerable.

[image: How To Turn Off FormKey Validation]

*(b) Turn off FormKey Validation for your controller*

Specify the action(s) you wish to exempt, from the FormKey check, in the "$_publicActions" attribute of your Admin Controller.

**protected $_publicActions = ['ENTER_NAME_OF_ACTION'];**

Code Example:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_publicActions = ['index'];

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "My Hello World! Controller";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**app\code\Test\Sample\etc\adminhtml\routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route frontName="test_sample" id="test_sample">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Test_Sample"/>
        </route>
        <route frontName="sampletwo" id="sampletwo">
            <module before="Magento_Backend" name="Test_Sample"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: I am not needed new frontname for every controller. I need to know why my controller redirects to dashbord.